# Greek characters displayed in some applications on Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, language-support

I'm loving Lubuntu so far, but I have been noticing certain problem with some applications, mainly VirtualBox.

Basically, even though my system is set in English (US) with regional settings in Spanish (AR), when I open VirtualBox it displays all the UI in Greek characters. *Not* in Greek, though -- it just displays the English text but using Greek characters. I have tried switching VirtualBox's language to Spanish and relaunching the program, and the same happens -- it displays the Spanish text but using Greek.

Here you can see what I mean:

[image: VirtualBox screenshot showing English words in Greek alphabet]

It also happened with other applications downloaded from the Lubuntu Software Center, such as Wine Launcher Creator. I guess it's an encoding problem? I tried googling it but all the answers I find deal with language settings, which clearly isn't the problem here, since the program is in fact displayed in the language I want -- it's the way the characters are displayed that isn't right.

Comment: Sounds like a font dedicated for cyrillic letters is being used, so maybe you should look for font settings for the applications in question.

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson Could you be a bit more specific? I tried looking at VirtualBox's settings but I really couldn't find anything that could point to the problem. Plus this also happens in other applications, so it seems to me like it's OS-related. Is there a way in Lubuntu to configure certain applications to display their UI with a specific font?

Comment: Do you have qt3, qt4 or both installed?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't be more specific, because I use neither Lubuntu nor VirtualBox myself. It was just an attempt to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Jan I think I don't? Is this what originated the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, I tested installing VirtualBox on my main machine with Linux Mint 17 Qiana, and turns out the same happened, so I tried to look more in depth regarding [what Gunnar Hjalmarsson said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530366/cyrilic-characters-displayed-in-some-applications-on-lubuntu-14-04#comment723951_530366) regarding "fonts for displaying cyrilic characters being used" and it turns out they were on the right path.

For some reason both in Lubuntu's and Mint's windows options I had **Standard Symbols L** as the default font for any text displayed system-wide, and that was causing the problem. I changed it to **Sans** which looks exactly the same but doesn't produce the same weird display of letters, and now the text is readable again.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that my guess proved to be helpful.